# Logstash hostname split up

Tags: filter, elasticsearch, logstash, grok

My hostnames are something like "companyname-instancename".

When the logs get sent to logstash and then stored in elasticsearch, they seem to get split up at the "-".

How can I prevent this in logstash? Do I have to change the hosts field?

Comment: Can you supply an example record?

Comment: Can you provide your configuration? Or please explain your problem more clearly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch, being a text search engine, is analyzing the data for you and making tokens out of it.

You need to set the field to be not_analyzed to prevent this.  Since everyone hits this "problem", logstash will make a ".raw" version of the field for you, e.g. myField.raw.